# Partial JSON update on DynamoDB

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple dynamo table that consists of cookies and attributes:

```
customer
cookie
attribute_1
attribute_2
...
attribute_n
```

Right now, these attributes are variable and need to be updated upon receiving a partial JSON through and endpoint.

I made my mind into using the new JSON type field in DynamoDB (since that's our main datastore choice), and I intend to reshape the table into:

```
customer
cookie
attributes
```

Where attributes is just a JSON document.

**Main issues:**

- I have no way of knowing which attributes are going to be added
- I have no way ok knowing which items already exist (save from making an extra query)
- I'd like to avoid a super complex code to do this

**Main goal:**

- In an ideal world, there should be some way of having or not an item in dynamo and passing the primary key along with some JSON and then having the DB partially update the existing JSON.

So far I've seen this kind of code:

```
DynamoDB dynamo = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(...)); 
Table table = dynamo.getTable("people"); 

table.updateItem(
  new UpdateItemSpec()
      .withPrimaryKey("person_id", 123)
      .withUpdateExpression("SET document.current_city = :city")
      .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":city", "Seattle")));
```

But I'd like to avoid making an extra query (to know if I need to create or update) and constructing all the update expressions.
Is there a way to do this?

Here is a full example just in case:

1) Receive the following JSON in the API:

```
{"name": "John"}
```

Expected dynamo attribute:

```
attributes={"name": "John"}
```

2) Receive the following JSON in the API:

```
{"age": 12}
```

Expected dynamo attribute:

```
attributes={"name": "John", "age": 12}
```

And so on. The primary key is constructed from the request cookie / customer.

My hopes for this existing comes from the fact that dynamo supports the smart `updateItem` (which I'm currently using) that allows to specify only some attributes to update or create an item.

Comment: When you say new JSON type field, are you referring to document data types (Map or List)?

Comment: @notionquest yes, exactly. I also have seen a `withJson()` as input for the `Item` class